# How do I create Unicode databases in PostgreSQL 8.4?

Tags: postgresql

I installed the **postgresql-8.4** package with default options. Everything worked fine, however I can't seem to manage to create unicode databases:

```
-- This doesn't work
createdb test1 --encoding UNICODE

-- This works
createdb test2
```

The error message,

```
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (SQL_ASCII)
```

is a bit puzzling because (afaik) I don't use a template for creating the new db, or is it implicitely referring to the default "postgres" database for some reason ?

Or maybe I'm missing a setting in a `.conf` file ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The template it is referring to is `template1`, which is implicitly used if you don't specify another template.

The quickest workaround is that you create your database from `template0` instead, using the `createdb --template=template0`.

You may wish to drop and reinitialize your entire cluster with a more sensible locale.  You have probably had your operating system set to use the C locale by default.  You can reinitialize the database system with these steps:

```
sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 8.4 main
sudo pg_createcluster --locale=en_US.utf8 --start 8.4 main
```

Use whatever locale you like, of course.

Comment: Dropping the cluster to modify the locale was exactly what I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: Man, after a lot of digging, that was what a was looking for too!
Nothing else could make PG working with Ubuntu locale, even changing it. But re-creating the cluster with UTF8 did the trick :).
Cheers!

Comment: You may want to use `--locale=C.UTF-8` (list supported locales on your system with `locale -a`).

Answer (score 3):

maybe you need configure the locale before to create the cluster

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: I think it worked for me!

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure requires sudo...

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean:

```
createdb test42 --encoding utf-8
```

That should do what you want.